# Macbook pro 2017 non touchbar replace ssd

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, ssd

my ssd for a macbook pro 2017 non touch bar is dead, so i want to replace the ssd. Is this ssd is a good choice ? Or anyone can recommend me another ssd which fits ?[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDOyd.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

No. That's an SATA 2.5" disk. You need Apple's proprietary 12+16 pin SSD module, Generation 5.

See this page for an extensive coverage of Apple's SSD modules, including those in your Mac.

https://beetstech.com/blog/apple-proprietary-ssd-ultimate-guide-to-specs-and-upgrades

You either need a second-hand Apple OEM part, or a third-party new one, such as OWC's Aura range or Transcend's JetDrive 820.

Comment: I HAVE AN ADAPTOR  for the ssd to fit in, is the samsung evo 970 plus a good choice ? :)

Comment: You can use a standard M2 SSD with an adaptor, though obviously there's more to go wrong.