# Is it possible to replace Macbook Air 2017's SSD?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, storage

Mine is a 2017 i5 Macbook Air. I think 128 GB is severely limited for software development purpose these days.

512 is preferrable, because I have more space for Xcode, some VirtualBox VMs, etc.
Is it possible to replace the SSD?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420631/macbook-pro-2017-non-touchbar-replace-ssd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
The 2017 MacBook Air's SSD is not soldered and is replaceable.
It does however use a proprietary connector. You'll either have to get a compatible SSD from an Apple Service Provider, a 3rd party like OWC or use an adapter with an M.2 SSD.

There is a [guide available on iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Early+2017+SSD+Replacement/135947).

Comment: Ah good to know. Guess this shouldn't be difficult issue for experienced Apple repair shops